# Masking annotations in seaborn heatmap

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

I would like to make a heatmap that has annotation only in specific cells. I though one way to do this would be to make a heatmap with annotations in all cells and then overlay another heatmap that has no annotation but that is masked in the regions that I want the original annotations to be visible:

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

par_corr_p = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
masked_array = np.ma.array(par_corr_p, mask=par_corr_p<2)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.heatmap(par_corr_p, ax=ax, cmap ='RdBu_r', annot = par_corr_p, center=0, vmin=-5, vmax=5)
sns.heatmap(par_corr_p, mask = masked_array.mask, ax=ax,  cmap ='RdBu_r', center=0, vmin=-5, vmax=5)
```

However, this is not working - the second heatmap is not covering up the first one:

[image]

Please advise

Comment: I would use manually `plt.text` to put the annotations where ever  wanted

Answer (score 4):

I tried a few things, including using numpy.nan or "" in the `annot` array. Unfortunately they don't work.

This is probably the easiest way. It involves grabbing the `texts` of the axes, which should only be the labels in `annot` which `sns.heatmap` puts there.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

par_corr_p = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])

data = par_corr_p
show_annot_array = data >= 2

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.heatmap(
    ax=ax,
    data=data,
    annot=data,
    cmap ='RdBu_r', center=0, vmin=-5, vmax=5)

for text, show_annot in zip(ax.texts, show_annot_array.ravel()):
    text.set_visible(show_annot)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Putting `""` in cells passed to `annot` should work if you pass a `pandas.DataFrame` rather than a `numpy.array`. You can mask the annotations in a `DataFrame` like `annot_df = data_df.apply_map(lambda v: "" if v <= 2 else v)`.